# Changing Purple (#7266f0) color of Ferdi to Yellow (#edd75a)

Tags: windows, npm, electron

I'm building the messaging browser [Ferdi](https://getferdi.com) on my Windows pc. I'm following this codebase: https://github.com/getferdi/ferdi.

After replacing Purple (#7266f0) with Yellow (#edd75a) everywhere in the codebase, the purple color is still showing everywhere. What to do to make this Yellow color appear everywhere in the application?

[image: Ferdi Purple interface]

Answer (score 1):

You can change this color in **Settings** > **Appearance** > **Accent color**.

[image]